# Paypal API/SDK billing plans and agreements

Tags: php, paypal

I have downloaded Paypal's SDK from here: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

I am using Paypal Payments Pro and wanting to add billing plans and billing agreements.

Looking through the SDK though I find no samples or objects which would allow me to create a billing plan or billing agreement. When I look for examples of how to create a billing plan or agreement they seem to explain how to do it from scratch, without the SDK. It would be very difficult for me to attempt to add in billing plans/agreements into the sdk if they do not already exist.

I'm wondering if I am missing something or if there is a plugin for the sdk I can install to get access to billing plans and billing agreements?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution? i just don't see any example on how to do this in php...gives me an 'Incoming JSON request does not map to API request' error

Comment: they are currently working on adding billing plans and billing agreements. What I was told by Paypal was pretty much that this SDK is not entirely stable, and so they were pushing me to use one of the other two API's. Either way I am using Authorize.net now that they have lowered their prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billing plans and agreements will soon be supported by the PHP sdk, and at that point it should have samples that demonstrate their use. It is currently being actively worked on, please check https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK for updates

Comment: could you edit that into your answer, rather than have it as a comment ? Would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now available in the PHP SDK.

It is quite easy actually, once you figure out how to use it, and in Github Repo (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) they also added sample code to get started.

Fair warning to anyone who reads this : Deactivating a Plan does not suspend the agreement. You should suspend the agreement to stop recieving payments.

Comment: I was going to ask a similar question but I found this one. So I wanted to mention that it is available now but stakoverflow did not allowed me because of the reputation points. However the question is about whether SDK supports Billing. I guess now it does is an acceptable answer for those who did not updated their SDK library.

Comment: Ah, yes, reputation... it will also allow you to simply upvote other answers that already exist and that you find helpful. The comment below the other answer was maybe unclear, but pointing to the first SDK version to support said feature. So I first thought it was just an attempt at duplicating the answer... Anyway, I edited your post to make it a little prettier (and repair the link).